# vim.desktop - changes lost when terminal exits

Tags: command-line, gnome, scripts, vim, .desktop

I was thrilled to notice a GNOME launcher for `vim` in the `vim-common` package after I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04, since it offers an alternative to `gvim` (a solid app, though not perfect for my workflow).  But there is a problem with the `vim` launcher, reproduced easily as follows:

1. Right-click a file and Open With > Vim (not Gvim!)... `vim` runs on your file in a terminal.
2. Make some changes, but don't save them.
3. Close the window from the title bar, as you would close `gvim` or any other app with pending changes.
4. The changes are lost, since the `vim` process dies along with the terminal (leaving a swapfile)

I'd like to find a best-practice way of fixing the `vim.desktop` file (system version in `/usr/share/applications`) to make the `vim` launcher a viable alternative to `gvim`, since that default launcher is like an accident waiting to happen.

The option `Terminal=true` seems like a given, but `Exec=vim %F` is vulnerable to the window dying and therefore should be replaced with a wrapper script... but I need advice on

- how that wrapper might handle the signal of the parent terminal dying
- how to handle the dialogue with the user about saving the file

It seems to me like the second of these tasks is impossible, since you'd have to do IPC with the `vim` session itself to demand the file be saved or abandoned, according to the user's choice... but I thought I'd ask here before giving up.

I already know `gvim` is a workaround but that wouldn't be an answer to the question itself.  I am just surprised that this weak `vim` launcher is provided with Ubuntu & other distros when it invites catastrophe into the editing process.

Comment: This is somewhat very difficult to address. The problem is that what is being sent when you press close window button is signals to Xorg server . The server will then close/kill the window, and that means all the children of that window (including the shell and `vim`) will receive `SIGTERM` as far as I know.  Your best bet is to keep the swap files and remember to save them. And realistically speaking, vim is a command-line app. It's not designed to deal with signals from GUI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lay in pursuing my inclination that a wrapper script was needed, with that script providing the means to run an interactive subshell (`-i` option to `bash`):

`/usr/local/bin/vim-gnome-wrap`

```
#!/bin/bash -f
bash -ic 'vim "$@"' vim "$@"
```

... then edit `/usr/share/applications/vim.desktop` or copy it to a new `*.desktop` file, with these changes:

```
TryExec=vim-gnome-wrap
Terminal=false
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "vim-gnome-wrap %F"
```

Thanks to @muru for pointing out the other thread [Unix & Linux: Terminal and Vim](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32523/terminal-and-vim), where for the sake of the larger community I have provided a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been discussed on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32523/terminal-and-vim). Quite simply, there's no real way to do this. The simplest workaround is to run Vim in `screen` or `tmux`. Instead of:

```
Exec=vim %F
```

Have:

```
Exec=screen vim %F
```

Then, even if you do close the terminal, you can open another terminal and resume the session:

```
$ pgrep screen -a 
974 gnome-screensaver
7853 SCREEN vim
$ screen -r
```